# shell script : navigate to root

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, debian

I am writing a simple shell script which requires a root privilege.  Using the terminal if you type `sudo su` and you write the password it works definitely.
I want to pass the password to the script file and then pass it to the system to become root ex:

```
pass= $1
navigateToRoot($pass)
```

Comment: You can't.  And it would be a horrible thing if you could.

Comment: assume that I want to read it from another program. a textbox from a certain application and pass it to the system

Comment: If you need root access to do that, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You are right, LINUX ignores any interpreted languages, so this does not work on shell scripts. I learned something today !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to :

```
chmod +s yourfile
chown root yourfile
```

By setting the `setuid` bit, the file will execute as root (owner) without having to store or pass the root password.

Make sure nobody else can modify the script

```
chmod o-w yourfile
```

---

SEE COMMENTS:

SETUID does not work on Shell scripts so this answer is INVALID.

Comment: setuid doesn't work on shell scripts because of the horrible security implications if it did.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment on the question, I'm assuming you actually want to ask the user for a password in some alternate way, rather than having your password in clear text in a file.

You can use the `-A` flag to `sudo`. From `man sudo`:

> Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the current terminal. If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly
>   graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and
>   output the password to the standard output. If the SUDO_ASKPASS
>   environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper
>   program. Otherwise, the value specified by the askpass option in
>   sudoers(5) is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a password from a script, you need a scripting language able to do weird things on [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)-s, like e.g. [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) (which is based upon [tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/), a scripting language that I strongly dislike).

But a well configured `sudo`, or the less used [`super`](http://www.ucolick.org/~will/#super) command, or perhaps a binary executable (coded with great caution in C) which is setuid and invokes some other script, should be enough...